# Clickable SpannableString in android

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have the bellow code:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Translators");
ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // do something;
    }
};
ss.setSpan(myClickableSpan, 0, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But when i add the SpannableString into a String is unclickable and not underline

```
String thanks="Also thanks the "+ss;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
String thanks="Also thanks the "+ss;
```

The right-hand side of the `+` expression is a spannable string, the left hand side is a regular string (with no spanning support). The `+` operator on strings causes the Java compiler to just put `.toString()` after your `ss` variable (in a null-safe way), and converting the spannable string to a normal string discards the spans.

To fix it, get rid of the string concatenation. You could use `SpannableStringBuilder` in place of `SpannableString`, and use the `insert(...)` method to put the `"Also thanks to the"` in there without losing the spans.

There's a simpler way though, your question code came quite close:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Also thanks to the Translators");
ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() { /*...*/ };

int spanStart = 20; // length of "Also thanks to the "
ss.setSpan(myClickableSpan, spanStart, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: `TextUtils.concat("Also thanks the ", ss);` could also be handy